# Django static files templatetags.static

Tags: django

I am trying to open a json file in python. It is in a directory called json in static directory of my app. I configured the static files as per the given documentation.

But I get this error on opening files in python using `open()` function

```
def send(request):
  file = static('accounts/json/credentials.json')
  f = open(file, "r")
  return HttpResponse("click here <a href='" + file + "'> asd</a>")
```

The above code generates a `FileNotFoundError`

`No such file or directory: '/static/accounts/json/credentials.json'`

I also used this code

```
def send(request):
  file = static('accounts/json/credentials.json')
  return HttpResponse("click here <a href='" + file + "'> asd</a>")
```

The above code successfully gave me the response. And On clicking the link `asd` it is working fine and opens the JSON file.

I have googled a bit and also went through few stackoverflow questions but not sure what the actual error is, Can anyone help me in finding out. 
Thanks

Comment: This is logical, since the relative directly you here use, ignore the `static/...` directories, etc. Note that the relative path, is not relative to the `PYTHON_PATH`. I don't see why you need to open the file here, since you simply pass the URL through the response.

Comment: I am trying to store some data in json file and parse it on need. I implemented a simple implementation of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming `static` is the helper function from the static templatetags, it gives you the *URL* path to STATIC_URL. It doesn't give you the *file path*. That is set in STATIC_ROOT and you will need to join it yourself:

```
path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'accounts/json/credentials.json')
f = open(path, r)
```

Note though it doesn't make sense to to try and put this file into the text of a link; your second snippet is correct if you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` file there should be a variable called `BASE_DIR` defined.  You need to prepend that on your file name.  Something like:

```
  file = static(settings.BASE_DIR + '/accounts/json/credentials.json')
```

Comment: I guess this is gonna generate a path like `static/home/user/project_name/accoutns/json/credentials.json`

Comment: I am not sure what the method `static()` does.

Comment: It is just adding static to the path given in between. Actaully my static files are in `static_cdn` directory. (i.e STATIC_ROOT is configured to it).  My actual path has to be like `home/user/project_name/static_cdn/accoutns/json/credentials.json`

Comment: Maybe you do not need to call `static()` since it appears `credentials.json` is not in your `static_cdn` directory.